# mapStateToProps after form submitting return undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Can you explain me what wrong with my `mapStateToProps`?

I have Login component form like this.

I want to get state after action send data state to store but it returns undefined (`console.log(propReducerState.isAuthenticated)`). Here is my Login

```
import React, {Fragment, useState} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Link, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {LoginAction} from '../../actions/LoginAction';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


const Login = (propAction, propReducerState) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email:'',
    password:'',
    isAuthenticated:null
  });


  const {email, password} = formData;


  const onChange = e => setFormData({...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    propAction.LoginAction({
      email,
      password
    });

    console.log(propReducerState.isAuthenticated);
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1>Sign In</h1>
      <div className="message">{formData.isAuthenticated}</div>
      <form className='form' onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
        <div className='form-groum'>
          <input 
            type='text'
            placeholder='Please enter your Email'
            name='email'
            value={email}
            onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
          <input 
            type='password' 
            name='password' 
            value={password} 
            onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
        </div>
        <input type='submit' className='btn btn-primary btn-normal' value='Login' />
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  )
};

const stateStoreToProp = state => ({
  propReducerState: state.LoginReducer
})

export default connect(
  stateStoreToProp,
  {LoginAction} 
)(Login);
```

and here is my LoginReducer:

```
import {
  LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAIL
} from '../actions/typeName';

const initialState = {
  token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
  isAuthenticated: null,
  loading: true, 
  user: null
}

const LoginReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

  const {type, payload} = action; 
  switch(type) {
      case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
          localStorage.setItem('token', payload.token)
          return {
              ...state,
              ...payload,
              isAuthenticated: true,
              loading: false
          }
      case LOGIN_FAIL:
          localStorage.removeItem('token')
          return {
              ...state,
              token:null,
              isAuthenticated: false,
              loading: true
          }
      default:
          return {
            state
          }
  }
}

export default LoginReducer;
```

Thank you for your support.

Update: As I tested with all of your suggestions but no luck. I will add LoginAction for you to check it. Thanks

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAIL 
} from './typeName'; 


export const LoginAction = ({email, password}) => async next => {

  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
  const body = JSON.stringify({email, password});

  try {

    const res = await axios.post('/api/admin/login', body, config);

    next({
      type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data
    });

  }catch(err){
    next({
      type: LOGIN_FAIL,      
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: `mapStateToProps` function suppose to be passed as the first parameter to connect function

Comment: @Morta1 yes. can you see. it is stateStoreToProp. It is first parameter in connect

Comment: you're passing null as the first param

Comment: @Morta1 can you explain more detail to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. Problem is that I put it in form submit

The stateStore always change then I just put it under form submit and everything work well.

Also with that, the prop should be one only. I defined two props and it is not right way.

```
const Login = ({LoginAction, propReducerState}) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email:'',
    password:'',
    isAuthenticated:null
  });


  const {email, password} = formData;


  const onChange = e => setFormData({...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    LoginAction({
      email,
      password
    });


  }
  console.log(propReducerState);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1>Sign In</h1>
      <div className="message">{formData.isAuthenticated}</div>
      <form className='form' onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
        <div className='form-groum'>
          <input 
            type='text'
            placeholder='Please enter your Email'
            name='email'
            value={email}
            onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
          <input 
            type='password' 
            name='password' 
            value={password} 
            onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
        </div>
        <input type='submit' className='btn btn-primary btn-normal' value='Login' />
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  )
};

const stateStoreToProp = state => ({
  propReducerState: state.LoginReducer
})

export default connect(
  stateStoreToProp,
  {LoginAction} 
)(Login);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you're suppose to connect:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    // dispatching plain actions
    loginAction: () => dispatch(LoginAction),
  }
}
```

Please make sure that your connect function look like this :

```
export default connect(
  stateStoreToProp,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Login);
```

and **not** like this :

```
export default connect(
  null,
  {stateStoreToProp, LoginAction} 
)(Login);
```

Comment: yes. I changed and it has no helps. still return blank object.

Comment: can you update your main answer to see how your code looks like now ?

Comment: have you tried to debug to see if you're getting into the reducer/action?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how are you using the reducer

You should have something lik this:

```
export default combineReducers({
  test: testReducer
});
```

And then

```
const store = createStore(reducer, {});
```

Where reducer is the result of combineReducers

Then in mapStateToProps the result state of testReducer will be inside *test* property

Don't use stringify to convert the state to string, keep it as an object

Comment: As I changed it but it seems that no luck, It still return a blank object of state

Answer (score 0):

Your `connect()` has wrong parameter list. The first has to be `stateStoreToProp`, as the documentation suggests.

You should export it as the following:

```
export default connect(
  stateStoreToProp, {LoginAction} 
)(Login);
```

Read further here: https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#connect-parameters

I hope that helps!